# FATAL EXCEPTION: Background tasks android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I've loaded the apk on the console and the tests report only 1 error on a single device (Galaxy S3, Android 4.3).
The error is as follows:

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: Background tasks
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: server_preferences (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM server_preferences WHERE (name = ?)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:1118)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:691)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1436)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQueryBuilder.query(SQLiteQueryBuilder.java:400)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQueryBuilder.query(SQLiteQueryBuilder.java:294)
    at com.google.android.gm.provider.MailEngine.getServerPrefsCursor(MailEngine.java:1462)
    at com.google.android.gm.provider.MailEngine.getCursorForReplyFromDefaultAddress(MailEngine.java:1466)
    at com.google.android.gm.provider.MailEngine.notifyInitializationComplete(MailEngine.java:1371)
    at com.google.android.gm.provider.MailEngine.access$1900(MailEngine.java:135)
    at com.google.android.gm.provider.MailEngine$5.run(MailEngine.java:1291)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

I'm not directly using SQLite, but only using a `SettingsActivity` class which implements `AppCompatPreferenceActivity` (maybe the issue depends on this class).   I have seen other similar topics, but they always directly use SQLite.
Here the `SettingsActivity` I'm using:

```
public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatPreferenceActivity {
    private static final String TAG = SettingsActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        // load settings fragment
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content, new MainPreferenceFragment()).commit();
    }

    public static class MainPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
        @Override
        public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_main);

            // gallery EditText change listener
            //bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference(getString(R.string.key_gallery_name)));

            // notification preference change listener
            //bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference(getString(R.string.key_notifications_new_message_ringtone)));

            // feedback preference click listener
            /*Preference myPref = findPreference(getString(R.string.key_send_feedback));
            myPref.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener() {
                public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
                    sendFeedback(getActivity());
                    return true;
                }
            });*/
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
            onBackPressed();
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private static void bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(Preference preference) {
        preference.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(sBindPreferenceSummaryToValueListener);

        sBindPreferenceSummaryToValueListener.onPreferenceChange(preference,
            PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(preference.getContext())
            .getString(preference.getKey(), ""));
    }

    /**
     * A preference value change listener that updates the preference's summary
     * to reflect its new value.
     */
    private static Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener sBindPreferenceSummaryToValueListener = new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
            String stringValue = newValue.toString();

            if (preference instanceof ListPreference) {
                // For list preferences, look up the correct display value in
                // the preference's 'entries' list.
                ListPreference listPreference = (ListPreference) preference;
                int index = listPreference.findIndexOfValue(stringValue);

                // Set the summary to reflect the new value.
                preference.setSummary(
                    index >= 0 ?
                    listPreference.getEntries()[index] :
                    null);

            } else if (preference instanceof RingtonePreference) {
                // For ringtone preferences, look up the correct display value
                // using RingtoneManager.
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(stringValue)) {
                    // Empty values correspond to 'silent' (no ringtone).
                    preference.setSummary(R.string.pref_ringtone_silent);

                } else {
                    Ringtone ringtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(
                        preference.getContext(), Uri.parse(stringValue));

                    if (ringtone == null) {
                        // Clear the summary if there was a lookup error.
                        preference.setSummary(R.string.summary_choose_ringtone);
                    } else {
                        // Set the summary to reflect the new ringtone display
                        // name.
                        String name = ringtone.getTitle(preference.getContext());
                        preference.setSummary(name);
                    }
                }

            } else if (preference instanceof EditTextPreference) {
                if (preference.getKey().equals("key_gallery_name")) {
                    // update the changed gallery name to summary filed
                    preference.setSummary(stringValue);
                }
            } else {
                preference.setSummary(stringValue);
            }
            return true;
        }
    };

    /**
     * Email client intent to send support mail
     * Appends the necessary device information to email body
     * useful when providing support
     */
    public static void sendFeedback(Context context) {
        String body = null;
        try {
            body = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), 0).versionName;
            body = "\n\n-----------------------------\nPlease don't remove this information\n Device OS: Android \n Device OS version: " +
                Build.VERSION.RELEASE + "\n App Version: " + body + "\n Device Brand: " + Build.BRAND +
                "\n Device Model: " + Build.MODEL + "\n Device Manufacturer: " + Build.MANUFACTURER;
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {}
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.setType("message/rfc822");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] {
            "contact@androidhive.info"
        });
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Query from android app");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, body);
        context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, context.getString(R.string.choose_email_client)));
    }
}
```

I found this class on the web and it 's perfectly working with all other devices.